# URL rewriting, chain structured url for single point of entery

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ /index.php?mainp=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/$ /index.php?mainp=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ /index.php?mainp=$1&subp=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/$ /index.php?mainp=$1&subp=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ /index.php?mainp=$1&subp=$2&id=$3&%{QUERY_STRING}
...
```

I don't think this is the best way to write this rule. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well ... you can merge one with trailing slash and one without into 1 easily .. but the rest -- at all depends on the actual URLs. Please show few examples (the more the better) -- it will be easier to to write a rule then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /index.php?mainp=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /index.php?mainp=$1&subp=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$ /index.php?mainp=$1&subp=$2&id=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

1. By adding `?` before `$` you making trailing slash optional, so 1 of such rules will cover 2 of yours (line 1 = 1 & 2; line 2 = 3 & 4, line 3 = 5 & 6 (6 is not listed but I guess it does exist))
2. I have replaced `&%{QUERY_STRING}` by `[QSA]` flag -- does exactly the same (can even be considered more convenient).
3. I have also removed `A-Z` from patterns and replaced by `[NC]` flag (NC = ignore case). This makes all rules a bit shorter and therefore a bit easier to read.